# How to replicate only the structure (DDL) of Postgres (without data)?

Tags: postgresql, structure, replicate

I have installed 3 Postgres databases.

The first database is the development, the second homologation and the third is production.

I need to replicate the DDL of development with homologation and production, because I need to create columns and tables all the time.

How to replicate this operations, without replicating the database data?

Comment: Check out schema migration tools like Liquibase and Flyway. In a nutshell: you have to store ***ever*** change you apply to your schema in a SQL script, put the script under version control (svn, git) and run the appropriate scripts to migrate a DB schema from version X to version X+1

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but how to register this changes automatically if im using an IDE to do the changes (pgadmin)? Better if i simple type the create and alter statements instead? With SQL Server i can do this type of replication.... but i dont like SQL Server so much and its still need MS system.

Comment: Do ***NOT*** change your objects through a GUI. Create SQL script and test that. If you start doing ad-hoc changes through the GUI you **are** going to get in trouble (this is true for pgAdmin and SSMS)

Comment: Thank you for the advice i will stop doing that... Do you know some better alternatives, that generate the sql statements so i can construct the scripts automatically?

Comment: `pg_dump --schema-only -Fc` and `pg_restore --clean`. But really, use a change management system.

Comment: Craig i will lose data doing this?

Comment: I was able to do it using  "SQL Generator" from IntelliJ's DBMS tool(Data Grip).